# head doesn't work when piped a result from ls | grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep, ls

I am trying to print the first 10 lines of all files in a directory.
Currently, I'm using:

```
ls -p | grep -v /
```

to remove all directories from the result of ls, and return just the files in the directory. When I then do:

```
ls -p | grep -v / | head
```

I would expect that the first ten lines from all the files would be printed, but it doesn't work.

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: If a command does not do what you *expect* it to do, read the man page!

Comment: @hek2mgl obviously, that was the first thing I did

Comment: How can you then expect that `head` reads a list of file names from stdin and prints the first 10 lines of those?

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't use linux all that often, so I don't have a great understanding of it, hence why I asked for help. Head can take several files as arguments and will display the first ten lines of them all as in `head file1 file2 file3 file4` will display the first 10 lines of all those files. Knowing that, I thought that piping the result from ls and grep into head it would work similarly. Obviously I was wrong, but the head man page doesn't offer any help

Comment: Well, probably it's really hard to get when you are not used to UNIX shell environment. Use Linux more often! ;) One thing, and that is the reason for the downvote. Please be more specific in your questions, `it doesn't work` is not specific. You need to explain *what* doesn't work.

Comment: PS: one more thing. Simply `head -n10 *` or `head -qn 10 *` might be what you are searching for.

Comment: @hek2mgl  Maybe `head -qn 10 * 2>/dev/null` to get rid of the error messages for directories.  I would include `-q`, or else file names get printed (which is not bad), but directory names also get printed.

Comment: I see, in that case I recommend the `find` approach (which is even more stable than the glob (*)). For some interactive use cases `head -qn 10 *` would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming that what a command receives from standard input is arguments.  It is not.

When head receives data from a piped command, what it receives is a stream of data.  The `head` command is reading that data in the exact same way it would be reading from one file passed as an argument.  Think of it this way (this is pseudo code, it will not work) :

```
PSEUDO_PIPELINE <= ls -p | grep -v /  # Not valid shell syntax
head PSEUDO_PIPELINE                  # Not valid shell syntax
```

There actually is a (valid) way to express just that, and it is called process substitution :

```
head <(ls -p | grep -v /)
```

This will achieve the exact same (unwanted) result that you observed, but makes it more obvious that the command preceding the pipe is really a file, not an argument list.

Standard input (as well as output streams standard output and standard error) is something each command receives from its launching context.  It is like a "hidden argument" if you want, and the process can interact with it (by reading from it until it reaches the end of the file, because it is a special file, but a file nonetheless).

Now you should understand why what you are getting is the first 10 10 lines of output of the preceding commands, and NOT the first 10 lines of each file listed.

You could achieve what you want with something like this :

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec printf "\n%s ------\n" {} \; -exec head {} \;
```

This finds each file, and then prints a header/separator line, and the first lines of each file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's a great explanation. Should the example that you provided at the bottom work as is? Or do I need to change something to make it specific?

Comment: @FlapJack  It should work as is (it will use files from the current directory).  If you want to remove the header/separator line and just have file content all printed in a continuous fashion, you can simplify the command by removing the part from the first `-exec` to the first `\;`.

Comment: yes it does, I'd tried it but hadn't noticed the space after printf so it was failing. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

To find all the files which are not directories in the current directory:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Then you can use `-exec` to run a command on each of those files.